# What is the saying or idiom or word that means when "friends" don’t need you anymore it seems like they don’t know you anymore

Tags: word-choice, idioms, popular-refrains

there are some people who are your friend in the time of need,and they ignore you the other times,so what do you call them? a poet calls them "flies around a sweetmeat".

Comment: It's a full sentence, with a melody: [_Nobody knows you when you're down and out_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0b-OHZI1Q5w).

Answer (score 10):

**"a fair-weather friend"** is an idiom.

> - "someone who is your friend only when things are pleasant or going well for you" [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fair-weather+friend)
> - "loyal or helpful only during times of success and happiness" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair-weather)

You could also say "an opportunistic friend", "an opportunistic friendship"

Comment: Another quote for you, from Ambrose Bierce’s _The Devil’s Dictionary_: “**FRIENDSHIP**, _n_. A ship big enough to carry two in fair weather, but only one in foul.”

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is "false friends."

Answer (score 1):

> "What you mean, 'We,' kemosabe?"

This [the following additions, to obey the site's rules to the letter] is very much like having to explain a joke after you've told it, but [Howard Schweber writes at The World Post, 1969](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/howard-schweber/what-you-mean-we-kemosabe_b_360034.html):

> In a classic Mad Magazine cartoon ... the Lone Ranger and Tonto are
>   surrounded by a horde of hostile Indian warriors. The Lone Ranger says
>   to Tonto "what do we do, now?," to which Tonto replies, "what you mean
>   'we,' kemosabe?"

[Tonto usually referred to his senior partner as 'kemosabe'] [and the 'real' Tonto wouldn't have dreamt of such disloyalty]

The joke is old and quite well known. At the link [Punchline Regularly Tossed Out Without the Jokes They Come From](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-687245.html), 'Chanteuse' adds: 'I always heard this said, "What mean WE, white man?" ' I came across it recently in one of Trow's *Maxwell* novels.

Comment: You should probably add a reference/link or two to this one. To anyone who (like me) has never seen _The Lone Ranger_, this answer makes little sense, and the final word none at all.

Comment: Then how did _you_ make sense of it?

Comment: By failing to find it in two dictionaries, then googling it and finding it on Wikipedia… and I'm still not sure I _quite_ get it. Answers should be self-contained at least to the extent that they give the reader access to more information about difficult or obscure elements without him having to fend for himself googling unknown entities.

Comment: Strange. A Google search for "What you mean, 'We,' kemosabe?" (notice I included exterior double inverted commas just to be helpful) gives the 'World Post' explanation of the saying (and its probable origin) as the first of 50 000 purported hits. I should think it's a witticism familiar to many on the site. "False friends" is equally easy to find, which is why I didn't add the comment 'Answers should be self-contained at least to the extent that they give the reader access to more information about difficult or obscure elements without him having to fend for himself googling unknown entities'.

Comment: _False friends_ doesn’t require any further information than that given in the words themselves to understand the phrase: it is the sum of the literal meanings of _false_ and _friend_. That doesn’t mean an explanation or reference shouldn’t be given; but yours is (apparently) a direct quote, and its meaning cannot be deduced simply from the words themselves, which makes it all the more relevant to include a source and an explanation. I have to admit I am quite baffled as to why you think this otherwise integral part of an SE answer does not apply here. As it is, this is not a useful answer.

Comment: Can I get away with 'Lone Ranger'?

Answer (score 0):

Although not exact you may also want to consider

> Left out in the cold

or

> Fair weather friend

or

> Dropped like a hot potato

Individual words which apply to the set of circumstances you describe are

> Ostracised