# Idiom or expression criticizing people who ignore you right after getting what they wanted/ were after

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

There is an idiom in Persian that literally says: "(to be ignored right after) **somebody's donkey has crossed or passed (over) the bridge"**

We use it in situations where someone (now feels relieved and) ignores or treats us much differently after:

- We have helped them to overcome or reach a solution to a problem, but as soon as they feel relieved, they start treating us as if we are now strangers or even annoying to them! (i.e. They totally forget the help they received.)
- We have provided them with something they needed (like a piece of information or news, a confirmation, an acceptance or agreement, money, etc), but since their need has been met, they don't think twice about ignoring us.

As you know, donkeys are stubborn and when they perceive danger, you can't force them to do anything. So I think the origin of this idiom might have been like this: someone's donkey refrained from crossing the bridge, so they asked a friend to help them get the donkey over the bridge, but after being on the other side, they forgot about their friend or treated them ungratefully.

Example scenarios:

1. Your friend calls and desperately asks you to lend a large sum of money otherwise they will go to jail. They promise to pay back the sum in two months. You lend the money and they say you are their best friend.
   After three months they still haven't paid you back. You need the money, so you call and ask them when they would repay it.  They promise the following month! A month goes by and still no sign.  So you call them again on the 6th month. They get angry and scold you about why you have called them over that trivial (!!) sum of money and ask you not to waste their precious time with these annoying phone calls since they would definitely pay you back as soon as possible! At this point you say:

> "Okay, you are talking like this because *your donkey has already passed over the bridge* and you feel safe and relieved now, but are you sure it was your last problem??! I will never help you anymore even if you are about to be executed!"

2. Joe and Jane have been dating for five years, during all those years Joe's behavior has been exemplary; he really wanted to marry her (so he was just acting according to Jane's wishes and requests).
   After Jane accepted his proposal of marriage and they got married, Joe started to show his other side and gradually ignored Jane's requests. So Jane told him sarcastically:

> "Oh, yeah! now that you've got my "yes", you are ignoring me and the reason is clear: *your donkey has just crossed over the bridge!"*

Is there any equivalent idiom, expression or proverb in English to criticize such people?

Comment: There is an expression "out of the woods", meaning "no longer in danger" - does that fit?

Comment: @Max Williams, Does it convey "forgetting someone who has helped you" too?

Comment: No it doesn't...

Comment: I see. @MaxWilliams. Actually it should imply "I have helped you but you are ignoring me, it's not fair now that you don't need my help to ignore/ forget about me." :)

Comment: There is an almost opposite expression, [fair-weather friend](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fair-weather-friend).

Comment: Yes, @cobaltduck, it is opposite.

Comment: In addition, related but not duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/217798/13804

Comment: In Malayalam and Tamil, "Palam Kadakkuvolam "Narayana Narayana" Palam Kadannal "Korayana Korayana!" **Until the bridge is crossed one prays "Narayana, Narayana",once the bridge is crossed one says "Korayana Korayana".** (Narayana is a hindu god, Korayana refers to a disrespectful distortion of the god's name.)

Comment: @NVZ,, close meaning, is there any English  equivalent to that saying ?

Comment: You can get this in just one word - "[ingrate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingrate)", "a person who does not show proper appreciation or thanks for something : an ungrateful person"

Comment: Hope you don't mind the substantial edit, it's not supposed to be perfect, but I think the question reads more smoothly now. You can of course rollback the edit.

Comment: Oh, not at all, @Mari-Lou A. Thank you so much, it's a big help. Seeing this edit made my day. ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibly relevant U.S. English expression is "**I was just a stepping stone** [for him or her]," where "stepping stone" is understood to be a secure place to set your foot down as you make your way along a muddy walkway, say, or across a small stream. The idea is that you help the person along or across as he or she advances, and then the person leaves you behind.

After helping a person like the one you describe, I've sometimes had the impulse to say "See you next time you need me!" But that would be mean-spirited, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks,@Sven Yargs. Thanks. it seems relevant to my first example. And for your question: yes, that would be mean-spirited. :)

Comment: Related to stepping on things, there's "Be careful who you step on when climbing the ladder, you might meet them again on your way down"

Answer (score 7):

I'd call this person a

> **[fair weather friend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair-weather_friend)** : One who is friendly, helpful, or available only when it is advantageous or convenient to be so.

I'd say:

> Okay, you are talking like this because *you are a fair weather friend* and you feel safe and relieved now, but are you sure it was your last problem?

Comment: Thanks, @Peter K. How should I use it in my examples for criticizing  those people?  :)

Comment: Isn't that basically an opportunist?

Comment: @MorganFR : Possibly, but *you are an opportunist* sounds less interesting for me than *you are a fair weather friend*. :-)

Comment: It does sound more interesting, provided your interlocutor knows what it means.

Answer (score 4):

***A friend in need is a friend indeed***

> This phrase is interesting because there are various interpretations of its meaning.
>
> There is some debate about the meaning of this expression.
>   Firstly, is it 'a friend in need is a friend indeed' or 'a friend in need is a friend in deed'? Secondly, is it 'a friend (when you are) in need' or 'a friend (who is) in need'? If the former, then the phrase means: 'someone who helps you when you are in need is a true friend'. **If the latter, it is 'someone who needs your help becomes especially friendly in order to obtain it'** (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-friend-in-need.html)

[***fly by night***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22fly+by+night+friend%22&biw=573&bih=376&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA6avW7rPMAhXFbxQKHbxzBxgQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)

> (*idiomatic, derogatory*) A person or business that appears and disappears rapidly, or gives an impression of transience.
>
> [Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/fly-by-night#32qgXsY0m5pK7JBS.99)
>
> A slang term used to describe someone or more than one person (can be as large as a business or any other entity) who is extremely unreliable, unless they want something from you. To put these dirtbags in their place, one must confront them directly face to face. This term is different than a flake, as a fly by night DOES contact a person, but only when they want something, whereas a flake or flaky person DOES NOT.
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://fr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fly+by+night)

Answer (score 3):

The most common idiom I can think of is to say ***Now that he's got what he wanted out of me...*** followed by something like ***...I shall not be able to rely on him any more***.

Variations of this might include *Now that I've got him out of trouble...*; *now that he doesn't need me any more...* etc.

But sadly I can't think of any English saying which is equivalent to the donkey passing over the bridge.

Answer (score 3):

*"Well you got yours so fuck everyone else right?"* –[reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/andhetomsun)

Answer (score 3):

The following quotes (*not all proverbs*) are related  to thankfullessness:

- No one sees how much you do for them, they only see what you don't do.
- Most people return small favors, acknowledge medium ones and repay greater ones with ingratitude. *Benjamin Franklin (1706-1790)*.
- When our perils are past, shall our gratitude sleep? *George Canning (1770-1827), British Prime Minister*.

Derived from the last one, you may say:

> Okay, I see that your gratitude sleeps when the perils are past. Feeling safe and relieved now, are you sure that it was your last problem ?

In an ironic manner, one may quote Stalin that said that "Gratitude is a sickness suffered by dogs".

Comment: It seems that your example has close meaning with my example, @Graffito. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Though not formal, you could say something to the tune of "You **used** me and **threw** me away." for criticism.
Another expression related to the situation described is 'in times of need, one has to bow before the buffoon'; implying that a person is only seeking help because he/she is in dire need of it.

Comment: Interesting and useful expressions, @VSI. Thanks. Actually, that Persian idiom is not formal either. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Casting pearls before swine" - To give things of value to those who will not understand or appreciate it.

"No good deed goes unpunished"

"Passed along like yesterday's gossip"

"The sword has forgotten the smith that forged it."

Answer (score 2):

I had to look up these English proverbs up as they've fallen out of fashion, but they speak about **ingratitude**.

> - When I had thatched his house, he would have hurled me from the roof.
> - Save a thief from the gallows and he’ll be the first to cut your throat.
> - it is an ill guest that never drinks to his host
>
> <sub>[*A compleat Collection of English Proverbs*](https://books.google.it/books?id=VuhDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=it%20is%20an%20ill%20guest%20that%20%22never%20drinks%20to%20his%20host%22&source=bl&ots=p3-fNflwwQ&sig=dSeKAdroONd0oiljDADhnErhCTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinhIqglbvMAhULVRoKHTlLAK8Q6AEILjAG#v=onepage&q=it%20is%20an%20ill%20guest%20that%20%22never%20drinks%20to%20his%20host%22&f=false) (1737) By John Ray</sub>

However, in the situations described by the OP, I am struck more by the deceptive nature of the people than their ingratitude. I would suggest the following idioms

1. **[use](https://books.google.it/books?id=VuhDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=it%20is%20an%20ill%20guest%20that%20%22never%20drinks%20to%20his%20host%22&source=bl&ots=p3-fNflwwQ&sig=dSeKAdroONd0oiljDADhnErhCTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinhIqglbvMAhULVRoKHTlLAK8Q6AEILjAG#v=onepage&q=it%20is%20an%20ill%20guest%20that%20%22never%20drinks%20to%20his%20host%22&f=false) someone for your own ends** (=to get what you want)

   > Liz has always used people for her own ends.

In the situations described by the OP one might tell the assisted friend, or newly wedded husband

> You just used me for your own ends, didn't you?

2. **take someone for a ride**

   > *informal* Deceive or cheat someone
   >   — *[it’s not pleasant to find out you’ve been taken for a ride by someone you trusted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/take-someone-for-a-ride?q=take%20someone%20for%20a%20ride)*

Answer (score 1):

Although the owner of the donkey has the good sense to wait until the requested help has been completed, your expression is otherwise somewhat similar to the fable (as it’s described in ‘Wikipedia’) about [“The Scorpion and the Frog”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog), where it’s shown that a/the scorpion will inevitably and inescapably “reveal or show its true nature, its [true colors”](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/show+one's+true+colors).
(from ‘The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer,’ via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)

“By your unkind words/actions [I guess] you’re just revealing your true colors [to me]. I’ll know better next time.”

Comment: Interestingly there is a proverb in Persian that says "scorpoins don't sting out of hostility, they do it because it's part of their nature", it implies that " this person has annoyed / is annoying you unintentionally, because they are like this by nature, and you cannot change them". Thanks, @Papa Poule. :) –

Comment: @Soudabeh That’s what I think it means in English, too! But a dangerous underlying flaw is still a dangerous flaw that can and should be subject to criticism, even if it’s part of the perpetrator’s nature and he/she can’t help but be that way. Similar to the flaw of the donkey’s owner (ungratefulness?), the Scorpion’s flaw (being a scorpion?) manifested itself in the fable by the scorpion acting badly against someone who was there to help him.

Comment: You are right, @Papa poule :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont bite the hand that feeds you.

Comment: This would not be used in the contexts cited in the question. Biting the hand that feeds is an act of rebellion. "The hand that feeds" is usually a long term care giver (e.g. parent) or an employer.

Answer (score 0):

" This would not be used in the contexts cited in the question. Biting the hand that feeds is an act of rebellion. "The hand that feeds" is usually a long term care giver (e.g. parent) or an employer. –
Matt E. Эллен
Sep 21, 2020 at 14:17 "

Not necessarily where one support go or comes from may dictate a reflection to one's relationship in system it doesn't speak of who or why and in or of the identity for why one acted and or why such system was acted upon.

In denial of truth, fact so rarely are acknowledge as potentially true; due to concern they could very well unravel the very ignorance another so badly clings to. So much so that one should constantly strive to always cite caution to ignorance be it willfully or blissful in nature as how true one understands or denies relies more on the capacity their reflection can identifies then the falluabilty to not concern their actions to/for/and/or against the system in which said action was or will potentially be acted upon.

Lol actually this probably doesn't even make any senses. Low i.q and dyslexic-esque troubles manifested while reading or when writing; posing exponential challenges when trying to explain something simple I try to understand but fail to categorically define. As truth doesn't reside within me but outside and my perception of it or belief in it shouldn't paint myself correctly; further associating a need to placate self scrutiny over assured confidence specially when a system is willfully going to be acted upon.

You know less then you do, and never more that you will. But it's a life better spent seeking a truth you'll never find, then living a life you could only regret not being able to rewind.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15500/announcement-ai-generated-answers-are-officially-banned-here