# Phrase or idiom request: To indicate to someone you feel like you are being used?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

What is a phrase or idiom that would indicate to someone that you feel like you're being used?

An answer would be much appreciated !

Comment: Related: [Idiom or expression for criticizing people who ignore you right after getting what they wanted/were after](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322297/idiom-or-expression-for-criticizing-people-who-ignore-you-right-after-getting-wh/).

Comment: Please include a sample sentence or two giving context. We need more context to judge which would be appropriate under different circumstances. What is the relationship between the parties? Your question has two close votes for lack of necessary context. Ideally, a sample conversation with a blank would be best, but that often isn't possible with idiom requests.

Answer (score 2):

> be played like a fiddle
>  To be skillfully manipulated by someone to
>   suit their own needs, ends, or benefits. 
>   [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/being+played+like+a+fiddle)
>
> play someone like a fiddle
>  (idiomatic) To manipulate (a person)
>   skillfully.
>  [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play_someone_like_a_fiddle)

or "violin". See this question on wordreference.com:

To play someone like a violin:
[Can anyone explain to me what does this expression mean](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-play-someone-like-a-violin.1203154/)

There's also something similar:

> be played for/like a fool

[Play for a fool (thesaurus.com)](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/play%20for%20a%20fool)

Even better, as I think it alludes to pulling a marionette's strings:

- pull someone's strings

However the only expression like this I can find in an official source is "to pull strings", and is often seen as "pull strings (for someone)", pulling strings meaning to make things happen due to influence or power.

> pull the strings
>  To have the real control over a person or
>   organization, especially in secret or without it being public
>   knowledge.
>
> [pull the strings](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+strings)

Answer (score 1):

[take advantage of](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+advantage+of) (someone or something):

To exploit someone or something for one's own purpose, gain, or agenda.

*It's unfortunately very common for elderly people to fall prey to online scam artists who take advantage of their lack of technological know-how.*

Answer (score 0):

**tool**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tool)

> 2. n. a dupe; someone who can be victimized easily.

As in:

> I told them they were looking for a **tool** to drive their getaway car, and it was not going to be me!

Comment: @PhilSweet edited in attempt to address your comment.

Comment: Yes, but it's still iffy. The reported speech isn't the same as "to indicate to someone you feel like you are being used".  Would many people say "you are making me feel like a tool?" or "I'm starting to feel like a tool here? I haven't heard it used in a self-deprecating way.